# What can I use to remove smeared, thinlayer of caulking/sealant from quartz backsplash

Tags: caulking, quartz

Recently had quartz countertop and backsplash installed and there had to be a joint in the backsplash. Whatever was used to adhere the joints, (caulking or sealant) was carelessly wiped across the backsplash in several spots and dried to a thin,milky film. I used a razor blade they left behind to remove excess product that was raised but there remains these areas obviously still with a coating on it.
What can I use to safely remove this film of their product?

Comment: Photos would help, different caulks/sealants can be dealt with in different ways. Also you might try the ideas in [this related question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78472/removing-caulk-from-quartz-bathroom-countertop?rq=1)

Comment: Try wetting+soaking with different solvents and wiping with a towel. You can smoosh a wetted  napkin onto the vertical surface to hold the solvent against the face for 5-10 mins before wiping. I would hit it first with 70% isopropyl alcohol, then if needed try other solvents in order of vinegar, lime-away, acetone, and naptha (zippo lighter fluid).

Comment: Why not call the installers back and have them fix the mistake on their dime?  It was a poor installation job, they should fix it!

Comment: Agree try a few different solvents.   If you go to an auto-parts store, they have a special chemical made to remove RTV gaskets (your caulk might be RTV).

Comment: Do NOT use any chemicals, you might damage your quartz top. Use the razor method.

Comment: The two big types of caulk are acrylic and silicone, and sometimes a combination of each. Silicone is like plastic/rubber, and acrylic is more like drywall mud that can be sanded. If you can include what kind of caulk it seems like, that'll help your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

They already left you the best tool for that

4 Inch Razor Blade Tile Scraper

But the blade needs to be replace every so often.

[image: razor blade]

A old used razor blade would not work, so replace it !

Source: Amazon

Just make sure you always hold it flat to the surface of the counter top, and not more the 45 dgr

Comment: What makes you think this would be any more effective than the razor blade the OP already used?

Comment: @brhans his razor blade was already used, and not sharp enough.

Comment: You need to apply some pressure so the blade doesn't ride over the caulk, and doing so is easier when the blade is in a handle like this.  You need to change the blade *frequently*.  Buy a box of 100 from Amazon, it costs less than a tube of caulk.   Using the leftover blade from the installer that he probably shaved with before he arrived won't get you results.   I wouldn't use 4 inch, I'd use smaller ones but you can experiment to find the tool you like.

Comment: The razor isn't going to work unless the surface is "perfectly flat".

Comment: @KyleB so what would you recommend to do in this case ?

Comment: @knowitall I said my 2-cents it in the comments above - Thx!

Comment: .... add... If the surface IS perfectly flat (i.e. glass-like), I'd be doing razor too.   They can for sure cause surface damage if wielded poorly, so some practice on non-critical surfaces would be wise.

Comment: @KyleB you are recommending using unknown chemicals, that can damage quartz top. The installer crew recommended razor (with new sharp blade)

Comment: Why guess?     https://granitecountertopsoregon.com/faq/quartz-countertop-care/#:~:text=Quartz%20is%20very%20scratch%20resistant,%2C%20dishwasher%20rinsing%20agents%2C%20etc.

Comment: @KyleB thank you for the link